# bug with input-group background under bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, windows-11

I have a new computer under win11 @ chrome v97.

The original bootstrap code causes a bug, as you can see in the attachment. [It occurs on the bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/)

If I add "`border-radius:0!important`" to "`.input-group-text,`" the problem is solved but without rounding anymore, which is not acceptable.

I think it's more a configuration of my computer than a bug with the CSS.

Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Small</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Default</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Large</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg">
</div>
```

Comment: tested with last version of Firefox: it works well

Comment: Set the browser's zoom to 100%. Sometimes changing the zoom setting causes such effects. The problem may be caused by this.

Comment: @Sercan: checked, it was already at 100%. When I decrease/inecrease, the white pixels "move" to somewhere else

Comment: You should include in the post which CDN style reference Bootstrap is using. For example `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: @Sercan: it's on bootstrap website itself. V4.6.1 - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: No problem in Chrome: [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wjux.png). The CDN reference I'm using is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: I also used the style you posted last time but it was fine in Chrome.

Comment: you re under windows 11 ? it's probably something linked to my computer. But don't know what. It's a fresh installation of win11/chrome

Comment: I wrote to isolate the problem. I am using windows 10. Apparently this is an issue that occurs under Windows 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

The problem was not directly linked to bootstrap. The code below causes exactly the same problem:

```
<style>
    #test{
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: block;
        height: 56px;
        width: 195px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```

To solve the issue:

1. Open Google Chrome Settings.
2. Go to the Advanced menu.
3. Select System.
4. **Disable** Hardware Acceleration toggle.